# Get rid of directory of unknown user

Tags: linux, centos, centos-5

I'm constantly failing to do something usefull to a directory.

`ls` gives this output:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 root     1000     0 19. Jul 14:03 backup
```

Here I'm trying to remove, move or chown this directory without success. Any ideas to fix this? After all I need a `backup` directory which can be chowned to an other user.

```
[root@www004 /]# chown root:root backup
chown: Change the owner of "backup": Invalid argument
[root@www004 /]# mv backup trash
mv: Move the "backup" to "trash" is not possible: Device or resource busy
[root@www004 /]# rm -rf backup
rm: remove directory "backup" is not possible: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: Google translate my friend. ;-). Dont worry I edited the question for you with the translations. By the way... this "backup" folder is in the host computer or is it a mounted to it?

Comment: It's mounted. Actually umount /backup was the solution. Thanks a lot! Feal free to add you comment as an answer in order I cann accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that folder its in a mounted drive, try unmounting/mounting the drive and try again.